# ngx-bootstrap Tabs breaking bootstrap table responsiveness

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, shadow-dom, ngx-bootstrap

I am using a ngx tabset that invoke various Angular 4 components that use Bootstrap 3.3.7 components. In one of those tabs I am displaying a pretty basic Bootstrap table. For some reason, I am losing table responsiveness within a tab -- 
the table just smooshes together rendering the fields pretty much unusable. Other tables in the app (not encapsulated within a ngx component) work just fine. Just to make things more interesting, I have a fairly complex form in a different tab that responds as expected.

For now, the app will use this library b/c it works well with AoT, so for now we are stuck using it.

Aside from tweaking the cols, I have tried a few different hacks that have worked for other issues I've ran into with Angular 4 over the last year. Like leveraging Angular built in shadow dom functionality (View Encapsulation) and that didn't work. I've also tried updating ngx and even played around with migrating Angular 4.6 to 5.2..that also had no effect. I can't migrate Bootstrap to a newer version since that will change the look and feel too drastically. Just looking for any ideas/opinions as they will be appreciated!!

Tabs.html

```
<div class="container">
    <tabset type="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" #tabselect>
        <br /><br />      
        <tab heading="Tab 1" class="active" name="tab1">
            <app-tab-one></app-tab-one>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Tab 2" name="tab2">
            <app-tab-two></app-tab-two>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Tab 3" name="tab3">
            <app-tab-three></app-tab-three>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Tab 4" name="tab4">
            <app-tab-four></app-tab-four>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

---

Tab1.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-xs-12">
      <h3>Select Data</h3>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
      <tbody>
          <tr class="header">
              <th class="text-xs-left col-md-0">Number</th>
              <th class="text-xs-left col-md-0 col-lg-6">Data 1</th>
              <th class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 margin-top-xs">Data 2</th>
              <th class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 margin-top-xs">Data 3</th>
              <th class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 margin-top-xs"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let x of data; let idn = index">
              <td>{{idn+1}}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-center col-md-3 margin-top-xs col-lg-4">
                  <select class="col-md-2 margin-top-xs form-control" [(ngModel)]="data[idn].data1">
                  <option value="">Please select prefix</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let x of data" type="text">{{x.data1}}</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
              <td class="text-xs-center col-md-3 margin-top-xs col-lg-4">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" />
              </td>
              <td class="col-md-3 margin-top-xs col-lg-4">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
              </td>
              <td class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-right margin-top-xs">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

snippet from Tab1.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Inject, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

import { Data } from '../App/Models/Data';
import { TData } from '../App/Models/TData';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tab-one',
    templateUrl: './Tab1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tab-one.component.css'],
    providers: [ModalService, { provide: BsDropdownConfig, useValue: { autoClose: false } }]//,
    //encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native ## this will enable ng Shadow Dom
})
export class TabOneComponent implements OnInit {

    tableData: Data[];
    tupleData: TData[];
```

***** EDIT - Included a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZEtG5mMnLdnS5y9yR1Wy?p=preview) and simplified the code some more. I promise to become a better poster!! ******

**** EDIT2 - A Plunker w/out the tabs https://plnkr.co/edit/n1dnAHvcWa2ENzIP9v7H?p=preview

Must be noted that I am seeing this behavior in dev-tools within my application, but dev tools <s>WITHIN THE PLUNKER LIVE POP UP PREVIEW TOOL does not seem to allow the responsive form-factor button at the top-left corner of the UI.  Not sure how else I can simulate this</s>

Responsive behavior functions in both Chrome and Firefox using Plunker for this example. But, Firefox allows formal form-factor simulation in the live pop-up preview in it's dev-tools while Chrome does not ****

Comment: It could have sense to put your code here. If it large you can use some open GIT resource and show the link

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I hope this works..

Comment: Could you provide a reproduction that shows how tables look like outside the tabs? for me they look the same here https://plnkr.co/edit/soB1HMU1YcEVU8dLWEQq?p=preview

Comment: @llyaSurmay Not a problem! I'll do it when I get a couple extra minutes today as I huge datatable using ngx on our app and it works like a charm for mobile :-( Just to be clear - the table should not smash together when the view port is small; the table should be scrollable so the data can be seen. Correct me if this is not the intended functionality

Comment: @llyaSurmay I just updated both plunker's and am able to get both of them responsive. But in order to do so I had to take out some of Bootstrap's styling. Therefore I do not think this should be closed but if you have a solution for how to get Bootstrap's styling w/out breaking the table I would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After refactoring and getting Plunker's working to demo the problem, I have proven that it is a Bootstrap issue (not sure if my fault or a bug) and NOT a Ngx-Bootstrap issue. Turns out it was really just Bootstrap form classes that was breaking the table

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th class="col-xs-1">Number</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Data 1</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Data 2</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Data 3</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let x of data; let idn = index">
            <td class="col-xs-1">{{idn+1}}</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data[idn].data1">
                <option *ngFor="let x of data" type="text">{{x.data1}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="5" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I removed the 'form-control' classes things work

Here is the final [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZEtG5mMnLdnS5y9yR1Wy?p=preview)